# Problems with item-based system recommender algorithm

Tags: c#, algorithm, linq

So, the idea was to build a system recommender on my project for anonymous users who are browsing my catalog of products. Based on that I've made this algorithm for recommendation:

```
public class Reccomnendation
{
Dictionary<int, List<Grades>> products = new Dictionary<int, List<Grades>>();

#region Item-based recommendation

public List<Products> GetSlicneProizvode(int ProductID)
{
    LoadProducts(ProductID);
    List<Grades> grades = Connection.dm.Grades.Where(x => x.ProductID == productId).OrderBy(x => x.KupacID).ToList();

    List<Grades> commonGrades1 = new List<Grades>();
    List<Grades> commonGrades2 = new List<Grades>();

    List<Products> recommended = new List<Products>();


    foreach (var item in products)
    {
        foreach (Grades g in grades)  //Sve ocjene aktivnog proizvoda
        {

            if (item.Value.Where(x => x.BuyerID == g.BuyerID).Count() > 0)
            {
                commonGrades1.Add(g);
                commonGrades2.Add(item.Value.Where(x => x.BuyerID == g.BuyerID).First());
            }
        }


        double similarity = GetSlicnost(commonGrades1, commonGrades2);
        if (similarity > 0.6) // treshold
            recommended.Add(Products.SelectById(item.Key));

        commonGrades1.Clear();
        commonGrades2.Clear();
    }

    //returning the list of recommended products
    return recommended;
}

private void LoadProducts(int ProductID)
{
    List<Products> activeProducts = Connection.dm.Products.Where(x => x.Status == true && x.ProductID != ProductID).ToList();

    List<Grades> grades = new List<Grades>();
    foreach (products p in activeProducts)
    {
        grades = Connection.dm.Grades.Where(x => x.ProductID == p.ProductID).OrderBy(x => x.BuyerID).ToList();
        if (grades.Count > 0)
            products.Add(p.ProductID, grades);

    }
}

//Cosine similarity
double GetSlicnost(List<Grades> grades1, List<Grades> grades2)
{
    if (grades1.Count != grades2.Count)
        return 0;

    int numerator = 0;
    double int1 = 0;
    double int2 = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < grades1.Count; i++)
    {
        numerator += grades1[i].Grade * grades2[i].Grade;
        int1 += grades1[i].Grade * grades2[i].Grade;
        int2 += grades1[i].Grade * grades2[i].Grade;
    }

    int1 = Math.Sqrt(int1);
    int2 = Math.Sqrt(int2);

    double denominator = int1 * int2;

    if (denominator != 0)
        return numerator / denominator;

    return 0;

}

#endregion
```

}

Using this algorithm I can recommend products to the anonymous users who aren't logged in to my system. Now what I have to do is to personalize this algorithm for the logged in users based on these criterias:

- algorithm must not recommend the products that he/she already rated...(1-5 ratings)
- algorithm must differ logged in users and anonymous users who are browsing my catalog of products.
- algorithm must not recommend the prouct to the user that he/she is currently viewing.

Now, based on those above criterias, the algorithm should:

- differ logged users and the anonymous ones
- recommend the different products to logged and anonymous ones based on the criterias that I've mentioned above.

Can anyone help me with this please ? I've been trying to find solutions for hours but no luck...

I hope I've been clear with the question. Please don't mind if I made spelling mistakes as English isn't my mother tongue.

Thanks !

Comment: What is your actual problem? As far as the programming goes, you have defined very well what has to be done. To me it seems that someone has given you this code and told you what has to be done, but you have no idea how to actually write code? Are you having any specific problems?

Comment: @Erti-ChrisEelmaa Sounds like a case of the homework to me

Comment: The algorithm needs to differs the anonymous and registered users. I've taken out the ID of the currently logged user from User.Identity.Name and now I've got all data about that user, but I don't actually know how to filter the products based on the criteria that I've mentioned above...

Comment: Next thing I added is IF(User.Identity.Name == "") (would mean hes logged in...) { LoadProducts for anonymous users } else { load products for the registered users (calling stored procedure from the DB to filter the products}. The error that I'm getting when I implement it this way is: An item with the same key has already been added , any hints ?